# Rendering Saltstack States

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

How do I render an SLS file in salt-stack which have jinja, multiple pillars and grains in it.

I need to save the rendered file in yaml file.

I already tried `show.state` module and `cp.get_templete` module, but am unable to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `state.show_sls` module allow you to display the state data from a specific sls on the salt-master.

```
salt '*' state.show_sls mysls --out=yaml
```

The `--output` option allows you to specify an alternative outputter to display the return of data. Salt will fall back on the `pprint` outputter.

**Note:** for `top.sls` files you should use `show_top` instead.

See the [`state.show_sls`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.show_sls) and [`output modules`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/index.html) documentation for more information.